# Selenium automatic selecting printers based on file name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-ide

I want to automate my web page so I won't need to select printers every time. When I click on the file I want it to automatically opens the printing view and selects the right printer for each file: `'first file': 'ZDesigner ZD421-203dpi ZPL'`, `'second file': 'HPAC on v-hpac'`..(First I click on the first file it opens printing view, selects the right printer for it and automatically prints it) after that same for the second file but with other printer.

I tried doing it with selenium IDE but it doesn't record when I click on the printing button. So I tried writing the script, it opens the printing view when I click `STRL+P`, but I want it to do that automatically without need to click anything. Do you have any idea how I can do it? If it is actually possible to do something like this? This is the code but not working:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

printer_names = {
    'File1': 'ZDesigner ZD421-203dpi ZPL',
    'File2': 'HPAC on v-hpac'
}

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://')
time.sleep(70)
file_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.docs-list li a')

def open_print_view_with_printer(file_link):
    file_name = file_link.text.strip()
    printer_name = printer_names.get(file_name)
    if printer_name:
        file_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.execute_script("window.print();")
        browser.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#printerName').value = '{printer_name}';")
        browser.close()
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

for file_link in file_links:
    open_print_view_with_printer(file_link)
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

use pyautogui to click the button or type something automatically
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui

if want to save it as pdf format, try this codes
https://github.com/ZouJiu1/zhihu_spider_selenium/blob/master/crawler.py#L550-L571

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#print-page

```
    printop = PrintOptions()
    # printop.shrink_to_fit = True
    # printop.margin_left = 0
    # printop.margin_right = 0
    # printop.margin_top = 0
    # printop.margin_bottom = 0
    printop.page_height = 29.7
    printop.page_width = 21
    printop.background = True
    # printop.scale = 1.0
      
    pdf = driver.print_page(print_options=printop)
    with open(os.path.join(dircrea, nam + ".pdf"), 'wb') as obj:
        obj.write(base64.b64decode(pdf))
```